# How to redraw custom collection layout when keyboard is visible?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, ios12

I have custom collection layout to draw cells using uicollectionview. Each collection view cells have input text view. When user enters text need to resize cell height.So I call collection view invalidate layout. But it redraws all sections and rows in prepare layout and keyboard dismissed automatically. I want to keyboard stay up until user taps close button. When user typing text need to increase height of cell height.

Why I go for custom layout is my app needs row span and col span options (Merge and unmerge cells) in uicollectionview. This can't be implemented in normal uicollectionviewflowlayout. Can anyone help me to advise this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**About redraws**

I have a custom layout in my current app. It consists of all kinds of cells including cells with text fields. I start editing the cell with field, keyboard appears. Then I press the button on another visible wishlist cell which adds the product to wishlist. When product is added I invalidate the layout and the wishlist cell is reloaded. During all these manupulations the field cell remains first responder and the keyboard goes nowhere.

> But it redraws all sections and rows in prepare layout and keyboard dismissed automatically

Are you sure that you are not calling the `reloadData()`? It's not the layout who redraws everything, it's usually the developer who calls `reloadData()`.

> I want to keyboard stay up until user taps close button.

So, if you switch from `reloadData()` to [batch updates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates) - the keyboard will stay.

**About resize**

When you invalidate your layout you prepare new attributes for cells. Attributes with new sizes/frames. But the data source is the same. It means that `UICollectionView` will just move the cells around but they won't be reloaded. You don't have to reload anything! Just invalidate and provide new attributes. The field cell will automatically grow.

**Example**

In **About redraws** I described the way I reload the wishlish cell. Also, I added field attributes size change. You can now see that the keyboard remains and the field cell size changes. It now looks this way:

[image]

So, I believe, you just have to work on your layout. It is possible to implement the desired behavior. Good luck and happy coding (:

Comment: yes. I see this behaviour in my app too. My difficult part is when my cell textview is at bottom of uicollectionview. When user took focus in uitextview I have move my collection view content offset y position to top for keyboard adjustments(else keyboard can hidden input field). In that case when user enter long text or enter new line I want to increase uitextview height so I invalidate collection layout. So every redraw of collection view content offset comes to 0,0. So user don't see visible of uitextview(because when it redraws it will go to bottom).

Comment: If I manually set content offset to top after invalidate layout. App shows some blinking effect. Sorry keyboard is not dismissed. I am not calling reloadData, using collection view invalidatelayout.I just want to reload without any animation when ever invalidate layout called.

Comment: any suggestion on this?

Comment: There is nothing I can suggest right now. I will think about your problem and try to give an advice.